# can we access the jenkins master home directory from the slave machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I want to execute some operation on Jenkins slave machine but want to use the data present in jenkins master home directory, can I access the jenkins master home directory from the slave machine?

Please let me know any leads here!

Answer (score 0):

You can not access them directly but you can copy the folder or files from master to slave & vice versa.

[Plugin link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that one of the Jenkins/Cloudbees recommendation is to avoid builds on master.
Secondly, if you have n slaves with the same label (let's say BUILD) you just need to configure your job with this label so that it will run on any of the slave (jenkins will choose the less loaded) having this label, and the checkout will be made on that slave.

Comment: By the way, as Jenkins admin I never use the master for builds. Just because I want to ensure the stability of the master, and I have no idea of what users runs on their jobs. The only jobs that runs on master are admin related jobs (monitoring, reports ...) I (or the support team) have developed. And these jobs runs not often.